# EventListener apply to previous line

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem because `scroll` eventlistener is located after `scrollIntoView` but still execute function.

```js
var idsac = document.getElementById(id);
idsac.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center'});
window.addEventListener("scroll", blur_close, false);
```

It's only a part of a code but the rest of it only changes css. So `id` is pushed to function from html `onclick="blured(this.id)"` and `blur_close` is a function that reverse everything that blured function did.

What I want is to not to execute `blur_close` when `scrollIntoView` works and to execute it after user scrolls.

It might be unclear because english is not my native language, so sorry for your pain.

Comment: I think suggested solutions may work as long as you have `behavior: 'auto'`. But if you change it to `behavior: 'smooth'` nothing works. I believe, debouncing the scroll event is the betterway to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser runs the JS code faster and in parallell to the redraw of the actual view. That's why the scroll event doesn't fire until after you've added your event listener.

Try wrapping your `addEventListener` call in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, like this:

```
var idsac = document.getElementById(id);
idsac.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center'});
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", blur_close, false);
});
```

This way you ensure that the browser performs the scroll and redraws the view before you add the event listener.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `behavior: 'auto'`, then you can remove the event listener before you call the function and immediately add it back:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", blur_close, false);

// ... whatever code you have...

var idsac = document.getElementById(id);
window.removeEventListener("scroll", blur_close);
idsac.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center'});
window.addEventListener("scroll", blur_close, false);
```

Comment: So I tried it already but it scrolls to an element and calls the function(blur_close) anyways.