# How to prevent hashchange scroll in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am trying to create an effect in an HTML page whereby a link with `href='#section1'` when clicked, changes the URL in the address bar of the browser AND scrolls to the element `#section1` smoothly.

The problem is that, as far as I have been able to test, I could accomplish only one thing. Either I could scroll to `#section1` smoothly using the `scrollIntoView()` method or I could change the address bar of the browser (which happens automatically when a link with `href='#section1'` is clicked.

**Is there any way to accomplish both of these things?**

Another thing I have tested is explained as follows:

I prevented the default action of clicking the anchor having `href='#section1'` using `e.preventDefault()` method of the click event and then called `scrollIntoView()` on the element. Then I manually changed the URL on the address bar using `location.hash`, but doing this last thing nonetheless caused the snappy scroll jump (before the browser could smoothly scroll the element into view) which I **don't want**.

Is there any solution to this? Or that I have to go with only one thing out of the two?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109682/eventlistener-apply-to-previous-line/67109836#67109836) is very similar. It uses `requestAnimationFrame()` to apply the event listener. Also, it would help if you posted a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check this out for few possible solutions [Prevent hash change from scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173690/4595934)